# How to come out of href attribute using xss?

Tags: xss, reflected-xss

I was learning about XSS and found a website that takes my input say `PAYLOAD` and converts it to `<a href = "example.com/search/PAYLOAD" > Link </a>`

After hit and trial, I found that it HTML encodes `"`, `'`, `<` and `>` . Is there a way for me to implement `alert(1)` here?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Just saw that `"` is forbidden. Sorry. I still leave the answer as it might be useful for some people.

Of course. There are numerous ways to do this.

One example would be using  `" onload="alert(1)` as the payload.

This will result in `<a href = "example.com/search/" onload="alert(1)" > Link </a>` which is valid HTML.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using the forbidden symbols?